# how to check if mysql table is used or an application accesses the table in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, mysql

A shell script is doing dump for a `mysql` table, but before dumping the table I want to check if this table is used by any other application. If so, I want to wait and enter in a loop until the application stops loading the table and continue with the `mysqdump` after it finishes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the command,

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES
```

**Experiment in my system**

I ran the command and this is the initial output that I got.

```
"Database"  "Table"        "In_use"           "Name_locked"
db_name   "table1"           "0"                 "0"
db_name   "table2"           "0"                 "0"
```

Now, I ran a `SELECT` query on a table (`table1`) that had around 2 million records. I opened another mysql connection and ran the query that I had mentioned. The output that I got is,

```
"Database"  "Table"        "In_use"           "Name_locked"
db_name   "table1"           "1"                 "0"
db_name   "table2"           "0"                 "0"
```

So from the above output, it is evident that the `In_use` column specifies that the table is currently being used.